# CS Cart related product options

Tags: php, smarty, cs-cart

I don't think this is possible with the current CS Cart set-up (v3) but some custom development wouldn't be an issue (or maybe an add-on).

When a customer selects an option I then want another option to be displayed. For example the option "Engraving Top" is selected "Yes" therefore another option (textfield) should be displayed to add the engraving text into. If "No" is selected the textfiled should be hidden.

I could possibly do this with JavaScript but it's slightly difficult to differentiate between certain options (as they all have random ids).

Is it possible to relate one option to another?

Answer (score 0):

You can hook by option name ;) because is the same on all product, only language diferences, but you need to add to options ex :`<div data-name="color" id="opt_12" class="cm-picker-product-options ty-product-options">`

Please tell me your cs-cart version and i can give you instruction how to add data field

Answer (score 0):

You should use Sequential options with exceptions.

http://screencast.com/t/3JWHn6i7M

For example you have 2 options.
Use "Frame" for photo. If "Yes", customer should choose a color of frame.

Use Options type as Sequential
Exceptions as Allowed.

Create New exception:

```
Use Frame:       [Yes]
Color of Frame:  - Any variant -
```

So in the customer area you will see this:
http://screencast.com/t/ecPh5A9Av

When you clicking the checkbox, Color selector will be available, "No" - will be blocked.
And if you change this setting: "Missing variants handling" to "Hide option completely" (on the option details popup in the admin area), the second option will be removed if you tick "No".